# Sum column elements subject to conditions in another column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a set of data with 3 columns - lines, stops and values. I want to sum the values for common lines and stops in the order they occur.

This is the data set I have:

Example Code:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Line': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1'], 
         'Stop': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A'], 
         'Value': [2, 10, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 2, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

[image]

This is what I want to create from this original dataset:

[image]

I tried doing this by creating a pivot table and using aggfunc to sum the values.

```
rail_pivot = pd.pivot_table(rail_d, index=['Line', 'Stop'], aggfunc= {'Value': 'sum'})
```

but it summed all the values for the common stops, not for the common stops in the order they appear. See below

[Output using pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgAHy.png)

Comment: Please, don't post images. [edit] your question and put the input/output data as formatted text.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I completely agree with your request. However, in this case, text extraction in image was easy, so I provided the code of input instead of questioner.

Comment: Apologies! Thanks for tip - will do next time.

Comment: @PandaKim Just curious, did you retype the values manually or do you use GPT? :)

Comment: @AndrejKesely manually :-)

Comment: @AndrejKesely Oh, I might have misunderstood your question. I first extracted text in image using Google, and then manually corrected some minor errors.

Comment: @PandaKim Yes, there are lot's of questions where the data are provided "image-only". I was wondering what's the best approach to convert the images to df. I might try Google (I guess it's some photo-to-text service).

Comment: @AndrejKesely i use chrome extension [image_to_text](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/%EC%9D%B4%EB%AF%B8%EC%A7%80%EC%97%90%EC%84%9C-%ED%85%8D%EC%8A%A4%ED%8A%B8-%EC%B6%94%EC%B6%9C/adkbpbalabenjlfngiefoifoebjpbjjl)(maybe google OCR). then if i drag, i can extract text and then manually corrected some minor errors

Comment: @AndrejKesely I was recently amazed by [claude3](https://claude.ai/chats), a tool that can impressively read text from images. It can even read graphs without numerical labels and return them to their original table format. The free version can still read images. (although with a resource limit of around 5 images per day i think) Overall, claude3 is the best image-to-text tool I've seen so far, and I highly recommend it.

Comment: @PandaKim Yes, I heard lots of good things about c3 (that it is overall better than gpt-4). Unfortunatelly, not available in Slovakia (yet)... But I use GPT - mainly for learning polars :)

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
cond = df.groupby('Line')['Stop'].shift().ne(df['Stop'])
grp = cond.groupby(df['Line']).cumsum()

out = (df
       .groupby(['Line', grp]).agg({'Stop': 'first', 'Value': 'sum'})
       .droplevel(1)
       .reset_index()
)
```

out

```
 Line Stop  Value
0   A1    A     12
1   A1    B      4
2   A1    A      1
3   B1    A     11
4   B1    B      2
5   B1    A      3
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Works perfectly! will take me a bit to work through the steps :)

Answer (score 0):

> ... in the order they occur.

If I've understood it well, you are looking to keep the values repeated, not the sum of them all.

This wouldn't be a `pivot_table` functionality, but `groupby`:

```py
df['new_col'] = df.groupby(['Line', 'Stop']).Value.cumsum()
```